# Sharepoint : how to create a navigation link in sharepoint home site automatically when a new site is created using ms teams

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

As soon as we create a site using teams there should be a navigation link generated in the sharepoint homepage?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by creating a [Site Design](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview) and then [setting that as the default design for Teams](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/customize-default-site-design)

Laura Kokkarinen has written a detailed blog on the topic:
https://laurakokkarinen.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-sharepoint-site-designs-and-site-scripts

Answer (score 0):

We could trigger flow when a site is created with site designs.

However, this doesn't work when we create sites in Microsoft Teams.

So I sugegest you create team sites first, and then use powershell to add link to top navigation in SharePoint Online:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2018/03/sharepoint-online-add-link-top-navigation-using-powershell.html